# Javascript start loader on keypress and stop when SVG drawn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a loader animation that I want to show while waiting for draw function to finish. However, currently the loader isn't showing and the SVG is immediately drawn (after waiting couple of seconds). Similar code with the loader runs if I put in on pageload but not on keypress.

```css
        .loader {
            position: relative;
            left: calc(50% - 25px);
            top: calc(50% - 25px);
            align-content: center;
            border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
            /* Light grey */
            border-top: 5px solid #3498db;
            /* Blue */
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
            /* Safari */
            animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
        }
```

```js
if (keyPress) {

  $(".loader").show();

  setInterval(function() {
    if ($("#SVG3").length > 0) {
      $(".loader").hide();
    }
  })

  //function to insert SVG3 into graphPanel
  drawSVG3()
}
```

```html
    <div id="graphPanel">
      <div class="loader" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: When key pressed you don't call `$(".loader").show()` ... you call hide before and after.

Comment: @trincot oh I just realised I typed the code wrongly in stackoverflow, I have just edited it. In my original code, it was $(".loader").show() but it is still not showing..

Comment: Does `drawSVG3` do any asynchronous execution? Or is it synchronous? I suppose it is the latter. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `drawSVG3` creates `svg` content synchronously by the usual DOM API, then the loader will never show, since the next paint is performed after the code has run to completion. By that time the set interval callback will execute immediately and hide the loader again.

You could delay the call to `drawSVG` with `setTimeout` so that a paint cycle can occur (showing the loader) before the work starts:

```
if (keyPress) {
    $(".loader").show();

    setTimeout(function() {
        //function to insert SVG3 into graphPanel
        drawSVG3();
        $(".loader").hide();
    })
}
```

Be aware though that the loader animation will not run while the SVG content is being drawn, since that again needs paint cycles to occur.

Comment: thanks! setTimeout works to trigger drawSVG3first :)